# Creating Custom gauge metrics with description and base unit

Tags: java, spring-boot, metrics, micrometer, spring-micrometer

I have created my own gauge metrics and exposed them. Below is the snapshot showing my code. Now I cannot set description and base unit of metrics using this way.

```
        int rate = (int) ((finPoint - initPoint)/Constants.TIME_IN_MINS);
        AtomicInteger n = meterRegistry.gauge("timeout.rate", atomicInteger);
        n.set(rate);
```

Can anyone please point out that there is any way to add a description of metrics using the above meterRegistry object?

Answer (score 1):

`registry.gauge` is a shortcut for a few common use-case.
If you want to set the description, you can use the Gauge Builder, see the [docs](https://micrometer.io/docs/concepts#_gauge_fluent_builder).